# Adjusting generated colors to make them more subjectively pleasant

Tags: color, interface-design, color-theory

Is there any formula or correction values for r, g, b channels, that takes into account **visual perception** of color and will allow me to adjust generated colors to be more pleasant while keeping them on approximately same level of saturation and lightness?

I'm using "vibrant.js" library to pick colors from images and use them in my app's interface. I pick two colors "darkMuted" and "vibrant" - one for the background areas and one as an accent color for controls.

After plugin returns the colors, I adjust them slightly, to ensure they work well together and have enough contrast. Basically, for the "darkMuted" color I'm setting saturation and lightness equal to 0.2. For the "vibrant" color I'm using the saturation of 0.8 and the lightness of 0.6.

However, while giving good results on the average, this approach lacks the adjustment for the subjective perception of color. As you may know a couple of colors with different hues and same "s" and "l" values could be percieved differently: one as a pleasant color and another as an acid'ish, "my eyes are bleeding" color (especially with the green and purple hues).

Is it possible to receive colors with an equal visual perception using this kind of approach? Or, maybe, there are better ways of doing the same?

UPDATE: As far as I know Google using color picking from the image in their Android music app. How do they know that picked colors work well together and visually pleasing?

UPDATE 2: By this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fhd5xuzcyerd5fc/AAAjI4DLBoa9apelMSkWcuuta?dl=0) you can find screenshots of the image and picked color pairs. I've added pairs of screenshots to show you the difference between "original" color pair returned by "vibrant.js" and colors with adjusted s and l values.

Thank you in advace!

Comment: Hello and welcome. I have removed the color conversion tag, or are you really suggesting we talk about what the color looks like on a another users monitor. If you need to be this precise then you lose by default.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, but I'm unsure if it's possible. Since colors essentially are nothing but RGB values, you need to find a *mathematical reason* to why you perceive one color as "pleasing" and another color as "acidish". Is it just subjective or do the colors you don't like have something mathematical in common? Maybe we could get closer to an answer if you showed us examples of the different color pairs you have found, and specify which of them you regard as "unpleasing".

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a way to create complimentary colours?  There are several online tools such as [Adobe Color](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/?base=2&rule=Complementary&selected=2&name=My%20Color%20Theme&mode=rgb&rgbvalues=0.1426941154013988,0.7,0.31903789371249025,0.7259027895902604,1,0.8126331454755158,0.3866510840130486,1,0.5807281039355163,0.7,0.27627447062138505,0.2688536520217247,1,0.8232366254660561,0.8201409211798314&swatchOrder=0,1,2,3,4)

Comment: @Wolff, I've attached the link to a dropbox folder with screenshots. Not the actual interface, but will give you the rough idea.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I mean the more generative (algorithmic) approach here. There will be tons of images, can't do it manually.

Comment: @AntonKosarchyn - the Adobe Color site has an upload button to upload an image for choosing the colours automatically.

Comment: I've looked at your examples and actually I like the "original" colors the most. Are you changing the values to get more contrast? Maybe, instead of setting specific "s" and "l" values, you should just increase the "s" and "l" values on the vibrant color and decrease them on the muted color. For example by adding/subtracting a number or multiplying by a factor? Just to make a more subtle contrast.

Comment: @Wolff, thanks for the answer! The problem is that some colors are already saturated enough and by adding saturation we can make them oversaturated. I can of course check programatically if the color already falls in the desired range, if yes - use it, if no - add or subtract value. But I'm affraid it would lead to the same problem - some colours will be ok and some not.

Comment: @AntonKosarchyn if there is  formula then it is very, very convoluted, the rgb space is not equidistantly spaced, likewise any hsb or hsl spae is also not equidistantly spaced (so blues and greens dont span same distance in your brain as the HSL lets you believe). Also what you call saturation and lightness is a extremely simplified version of what our brains perceive as similar saturation. So if you were to do this you would need to do this in a highly convoluted manner. Color is mathematically much much harder hen people expect, in fact youd need a huge lookup table.

Comment: @joojaa, As far as I know there is a formula for converting sRGB to luma where r, g, b channels have their own multipliers: 

L = r * 0.2126 + g * 0.7152 + b * 0.0722

So, I'm wondering maybe there is something close to this approach?

Eg:  if [hue] is in "a" range then [saturation] *= "y"; [lightness] *= "z" and so on. Does it makes sense?

Comment: @Anton Well its a white lie to children. It works if you do not expect too much of the systems ability to do deep reasoning on color. In other words good if you have a human adjusting but not good enough for what you do.

Comment: "the subjective perception of color" - I think you answered your own question here. It is subjective what is pleasant and what is not, and that changes by the eye perceiving it, the context it is seen in, the mood of the seer, and so on.  You mention downstream that pastels are universally pleasant, am I wrong to not like them?    God forbid someone finds this formula you seek... it will only mean they are mandating what is good and what is bad; a problem for those whose tastes vary from the mainstream.

Comment: @rebusB, Got it and would mostly agree here. I'm rather telling about something measurable, something based on average perceptions. So maybe it's better to call it "objective"? There are always edge cases, anyway.

Comment: I guess it would be better to refrase the question to: "How to make generated colors objectively equal". I think I should look toward the color systems like CIELab and CIEYUV that describe color more linear. Only I don't know how to do it practicaly. But even if I could adjust color values to makes them almost "equal" then there is still a problem of color distortion against original image. 

So, the right way seems to not edit colors explicitly, but rather to generate a bunch of similar colors from image and then filter them through some threshold and pick the ones that will pass

Answer (score 2):

It is **impossible** to create "pleasant looking" colors for everyone. There's no formula which can be used. Every single person on earth has their own biases and preferences. There's no such thing as "universal acceptance" when it comes to color or artwork.

Due to inherent frequency differences in various colors, it's also practically impossible to "match" the saturation/vibrance between some colors, especially opposing colors and especially using some formulaic approach. Some color ranges will naturally appear more vibrant than others. Therefore universally applying the same adjustments will pretty much always make some colors fall within your desired range, while other colors are way too over corrected.

Your current approach is as good as any. Find what works *for you* or your team, because ultimately that's all you *can* do.

Color choice is *far more* of an art, than a science. You can't *force* math to work regarding human perception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I totally agree with you that It's nearly to impossible to create universaly pleasant color. Maybe I was incorrect in my terms. When I told "pleasant color" I meant something that most people would percieve as pleasant or ar least not irritating.

Almost everyone would agree that pastel colors are pleasant, but just few would find 100% saturated and bright colors like pure 255 red or 255 green comfort to look at, or am I wrong?

Also, I'm not advocating my approach. Over against, I believe there is a better way of doing it. Maybe some correction table?

Comment: No see.. you are still making (incorrect) assumptions. "Most people" do not find "pastel colors pleasing". In fact, some people really dislike pastels. You **can't** mathematically determine what will or will not be liked. You are seeking the impossible. Human beings **never** have a consensus on what may be "best". It's **art** and NOT science. And you can't *force* it to be a science.

Comment: maybe you're right, and I'm asking for too much.
But Google somehow managed this problem with their notifications system:
https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM3QtH8IDvOyEUugMSxSNILDgHVM0YXEJOQftu32CPIq4Bd8DnStO5WwP-fcQHTDQ?key=NXU0QkNRTUJqR1FVUmJ5QnY4bUdLNTJvT0dHSXJ3

Comment: No. Google determined what **Google** thought worked best... not what the public would "like best". As I posted in my answer, use what **you think works well**. You can't chase after what the general public will like or dislike. It's a fool's errand. You can use some broad, general things such as [color preferences by age](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60330/how-to-select-colors-for-target-audience-based-on-age/60356#60356) But beyond that, it comes down to the designer's choice. If it was all a mathematical formula... why would anyone need a designer?

Comment: Google do their products for people, like you and me. So it's no longer about their taste.

I think the designers role is a bit broader - to discover a problem and find a feasible solution. If the solution would be to genereate the color programmaticaly, then it's time to find an approach to that) That's just my oppinion. Anyway, I appreciate your opinion too and your interest in this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Google creates their products to make money. Don't kid yourself. They aren't creating "for the people".. they are creating products for return on investment. I understand that you *want* this to be science. It's not. And there's no math you can figure out which will work. But, of course, you are free to keep trying. If all art could be programmatically created, the need for **any** artist would vanish and Google would not employ **any** designers whatsoever. All they would need are mathematicians.