# Method or algorithm for choosing a color that "goes well" with other colors

Tags: color, bootstrap

This may be more of a computer science question than a UX question, but it's a question of what pleases the human eye. Take Bootstrap buttons, for example. The version 3 button colors "go well together". The version 4 buttons also "go well" together, but are starker than the version 3 buttons.

If I were to want to find a new color that "goes well" with a group of existing colors, is there some way of mathematically interpolating or algorithmically determining a color that "goes with" the reference group of colors?

To use the Bootstrap example, I want a way to find which shade of, say, pink, will "go with" the version 3 button colors, without eyeballing it until I find something that looks pleasing. For the version 4 buttons, the same method should produce a (starker) pink that nicely matches the (starker) version 4 colors.

Is this possible, or must we eyeball it?

EDIT: I've marked this question as a duplicate, although it's not exactly the same.

Comment: No, theres no, easy mathematical algorithm to this. Mainly because the mathematics of color are mindbogglingly complicated. There are tools that are sometimes ok color palettes, but nothing that always works. But this is mainly because as nearly any combination may work so its not a very high bar to set

Comment: Note that there **are** some possible ways to quantify how aesthetically pleasing a color palette may be given a *specific demographic*. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60330/how-to-select-colors-for-target-audience-based-on-age It is still far more art than science, but there is some data which may at least point in a general direction.

Comment: Please don't edit your question unless it's to improve it; that brings the question back to be reopen. Instead, next time just add a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use sass or check [Colormind](http://colormind.io/). Colormind API can generate a color palette given one or more input colors

Answer (score 2):

​"Pleasing" to the human eye is a relative term and I am not sure if we can come with him an algorithm to solve it :)
Having said that, you can use websites like https://color.adobe.com for exploring and creating new color themes

You can check this link for other alternatives as well: https://www.topbestalternatives.com/adobe-kuler/